# How to add or subtract seconds from a datetime in DAX

Tags: sql-server-2016, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a datetime column and a int column representing a number of seconds. I'd like to calculate the sum of the two.

For example:

2017-08-01 18:00:00 + 180 (seconds) = 2017-08-01 18:03:00

The DAX DateAdd function only supports adding a year/month/day and not seconds, so I'm stuck!

Answer (score 6):

Given this table:

[image]

Adding a column with this: `=[Column1]+TIME(0,0,[Column2])`

Will give you this:

[image]